# Passing parameter / variable through two controllers in Laravel difficulty

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Data model that I want people to be able to view individual records of and then edit/add data to. I have managed to get the view route working;

```
Route::get('/data/{data_token}', 'DataController@show');
```

Data_token, is a unique string. This then uses this DataController function;

```
Public function show($data) {
  $data = Data::where('data_token',$data)->first();
  return view('data.show', compact('data'))
}
```

After which I can display the data on the page, and have a form for editing (actually its for adding data that doesn't exist, but whatever, same principle right).

On the form on the data.show view, I am sending it to a different view;

```
Route::get('/data/{data_token}/edit', 'DataController@edit');
```

This can use the $request variable to return the forms values, but I can't relate it to the data row I was previously editing?

how do I get the {data_token} passed to the edit function of the controller?

Edit( adding route files)

Noticed I forgot the {'data_token'} in the post route.

/Begs forgiveness

Comment: please show your route files

Comment: `Route::get('/data/{data_token}/edit', 'DataController@edit');`

Comment: please share your full route files, atleast show and edit route

Comment: In your edit view the `data_token` is in you url so there is your reference to you original data token? Or am i missunderstanding your question?

Comment: The exact same way you got your data token in you show method, If I understand the question right.

Comment: Think Sohel0415 was on the right track, had my routes wrong. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood how the routes and controllers work. What you're looking at is a fairly simple CRUD setup like the following;

```
Route::get('/data/{data_token}', 'DataController@show');
Route::get('/data/{data_token}/edit', 'DataController@edit');
Route::post('/data/{data_token}/edit', 'DataController@update');
```

Now your controller would have;

```
public function show($dataToken) { ... }
public function edit($dataToken) { ... }
public function update($dataToken, Request $request) { ... }
```

Then you'd have your form on the edit view like so;

```
<form action="{{ route('DataController@update') }}" method="post">
```

Laravels router will always try to pass in the URI variables as arguments to the methods provided.
Providing that I have understood what you need, this should suffice.

Comment: Actually, doing this I get a Route not defined, if I change the form action to {{ url('/data/{data_token}/edit') }} the page works and I can submit the form but there's no $data_token variable available to me? Am I missing something obvious again?

Comment: What does the controller method look like? If you used my code, it's `$dataToken`

Comment: It's alright I think I just got myself spun in circles, the controller didn't have the arguments for data_token.